# Reputation increase for no apparent reason

Tags: support

I recently posted an answer to a [topic](https://askubuntu.com/q/526527/39753).  I had no comments on this topic, and no upvotes on my post.  The post was not accepted.

Today, a few days later, I had a green flag showing +8 reputation change for this topic.  I see no reason for it.  It's not a big deal, but I'm really curious about why this happened.

Comment: You can always use the reputation tab of your profile to see the exact changes: http://askubuntu.com/users/39753/marty-fried?tab=reputation&sort=time

Comment: Doh!  I rarely paid attention to all those tabs; I usually just looked at the summary.  Thanks for pointing that out - I'll have to remember about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently have on that answer one upvote (+10) and one downvote (-2) = +8. With your reputation, you can click on the zero to see what votes resulted in the current number.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks, I learned something new.  I never knew about clicking on the number. I thought I would see both the +10 and the -2, rather than just the single total. This may have happened before, but I just didn't investigate why.

Comment: People take reputation too seriously, which is why I think downvotes against your posts don't bring a notification like upvotes do.